# hide() and click() methods jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide an element when the user clicks on the submit button.

```html
    <div class="form-group submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers" class="button">
        <br>
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" >No Thanks</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="no-thanks" style="padding-top:0;">
    <a href="#"><h3>No Thanks</h3></a>
</div>
```

```js
$().ready(function() {
    $('submit').click(function() {
        $('no-thanks').hide(); //or i would like to do this $('no-thanks').addClass('hidden') im using bootstrap
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're missing the selector for `$().ready(function() {`, it should be `$(document).ready(function() {`
2. You are not selecting the submit button, you need to add an `id` attribute to the tag then select the element using that selector.
3. You're missing the period for the class selector in this line `$('no-thanks').hide();`, it should be `$('.no-thanks').hide();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('.no-thanks').hide();
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="form-group submit">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Answers" class="button">
        <br>
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal">No Thanks</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="no-thanks" style="padding-top:0;">
    <a href="#"><h3>No Thanks</h3></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use no-thanks as a css class selector which woud be.    $(".no-thanks")

So all you're missing is the dot to tell jQuery that you're looking for a css class.

Edit: and I think you're missing the document selector in the first line:
    $(document).ready(...);

Comment: ive tried that in my plunker file but it still doesnt work... can you jsfiddle one for me?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7j0jmm5L/ sorry, took a bit since I'm on my smartphone. To remove or add a css class use .removeClass or .addClass: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are wrong.  You have `$('submit')` for which I'm assuming you're trying to target your `<input type="submit">` button.  The correct selector for that would be, in the given use case, `$('input[type="submit"]')`.

Furthermore, as others have pointed out, `$('no-thanks')` isn't going to select anything either.  You need to use `$('.no-thanks')` ('.' css class selection).

Further information regarding jQuery selectors:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Specifically for attribute ("type") selectors: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

&

For Class Selection: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/